# Need help with notation --- finite set of random primes

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, prime-numbers

I need help with notation for a finite set of random primes.
**Edit** I've inserted my take on the format from the answer. Does it work?
My attempt:$$\{X\in\binom{\mathbf P_{3,100}}{20}\},$$
$$\{p_{i}\in\textbf{P}: 3\leq i \leq 100 \land \text{#}=20\text{ (at random)}\},$$where I want the range $p_{3}$ to $p_{100}$ and I want 20 primes.

$$\{X\in\binom{\mathbf P}{20}\},$$$$\{p_{i}\in\textbf{P}: 1\leq i\land\text{#}=20\text{ (at random)}\},$$where I want 20 primes.

Is there a better way to show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had encountered this set, I would not know what it means.

Instead, write $\mathbf P_{n,m}$ for the set $\{p_n,\ldots,p_m\}$. Now we can say that $X\subseteq\mathbf P_{3,100}$ and $|X|=20$, or $X\in\binom{\mathbf P_{3,100}}{20}$.

Since we didn't specify what are the elements of $X$, they are arbitrary (or "random" if you prefer to stick to that term).

---

Or if you dislike that, you write say that $i_1,\ldots,i_{20}$ are arbitrary integers between $3$ and $100$, and then consider $\{p_{i_j}\mid 1\leq j\leq 20\}$.

Comment: +1 for confirming my suspicion about the clarity. I will play with it a bit to determine if it fits into my other functions.

Comment: The term "random" has pretty specific meaning in some branches of mathematics. I would definitely recommend sticking to "arbitrary" if the result to follow simply holds for any finite set of primes without restrictions, IMHO.

Comment: Is $\mathbf P_{\geq3}$ acceptable to indicate no upper limit?

Comment: Probably. Just be sure to explicitly define those notations in your text. None of them is standard.

Comment: Is $\mathbf P_{3,\infty}$ better?

Comment: Both are reasonable (under the disclaimer from the last comment, of course).